# Contiki IPv4 connection to 127.0.0.1 loop back address

Tags: contiki

I m new to contiki. I used cc2650 sensortag and now i m using cc1310 launchpad. i use beagebone as a edge router and one cc1310 launchpad as a slipradio. everything works fine. i can open Coap and web and also i can get sensors data on web and coap.

now, i want to send sensor data on our own ipv4 cloud using tcp socket. but, i cant create tcp socket to my cloud. Is it possible to create ipv4 tcp socket directly from node?
@g-oikonomou @adamdunkels @farcaller can anyone suggest me how to create ipv4 tcp socket to 127.0.0.1 ip address and 1502 port?